# Замена цвета

Tags: php

Нужно заменить серый цвет, на белый. По центру - прозрачное.

[w_70d6a7b3c0.png](http://vip.clubtone.net/src/public/wf/w_70d6a7b3c0.png)

Как это сделать?

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng(DOCUMENT_ROOT . 'src/public/wf/w_70d6a7b3c0.png');

// Получение индекса цвета фона
$bg = imagecolorat($im, 0, 0);

// Установка цвета фона
imagecolorset($im, $bg, 0, 0, 0);

// Вывод изображения в броузер
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Это не работает.

Comment: Сначала заменяем весь белый на красный.  
Выставляем красный как прозрачный.  
Заменяем серый на белый.

Comment: По центру и есть прозрачное.

$im = imagecreatefrompng(DOCUMENT_ROOT . 'src/public/wf/w_70d6a7b3c0.png');
echo 'Всего цветов в изображении: ' . imagecolorstotal($im);

Выдает 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если в картинке присутствует альфа-канал (прозрачность), функция `imagecolorset()` становится бесполезной.

Как вариант - это скопировать изображение через функцию `imagecreate()`, причем с сохранением альфа канала (ага, через эту функцию почему-то изменяет) и заменой цвета:

```
/**
 * 
 */
$im = imagecreatefrompng('w_70d6a7b3c0.png');

/**
 * 
 */
$tmp = imagecreate (imagesx($im), imagesy($im));
imagealphablending($tmp, false);
imagesavealpha($tmp, true);

imagecopyresampled($tmp, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($im), imagesy($im), imagesx($im), imagesy($im));

/**
 * 
 */
$bg = imagecolorat($tmp, 0, 0);
imagecolorset($tmp, $bg, 0, 0, 220);

/**
 * 
 */
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($tmp);
imagedestroy($tmp);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Answer (score 0):

Готово!

```
function imagefon(&$image) {
  $width = imagesx($image);
  $height = imagesy($image);
  $gray = imagecolorat($image, 0, 0);
  for($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++) {
    for($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++) {
      $rgb = imagecolorat($image, $x, $y);
      if ( $gray == $rgb ) {
        imagesetpixel($image, $x, $y, imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255));
      } else {
        imagesetpixel($image, $x, $y, imagecolortransparent($image, imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0)));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Использовать так.

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng(DOCUMENT_ROOT . 'src/public/wf/w_70d6a7b3c0.png');
imagefon($im);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: Проще заменить цвет в палитре, чем попиксельно изменять.

Comment: @lampa, уже работает. Переделывать времены нет.