# Как показать изображение инвертировав его фон?

Tags: jquery, php, изображения

Только белый цвет. Чтобы вместо белого фона был чёрный.

Comment: @Taypfoon, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Вариант для JavaScript**

Допустим, есть такая разметка:

```
<img id='old' src='invert-me.png' />
<img id='new' src='loading.gif' />
```

Напишем скрипт, который будет заменять белый цвет (255, 255, 255) на черный (0, 0, 0)

```
function recolorImage(img, oldRed, oldGreen, oldBlue, newRed, newGreen, newBlue) {
    var c = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var w = img.width;
    var h = img.height;

    c.width = w;
    c.height = h;

    // рисуем изображение на холсте
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);

    // получаем данные о цвете (RGB) для всего холста
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);

    // обрабатываем каждый пиксель, 
    // заменяем все старые значения цвета (old-rgb) на новые (new-rgb)
    for (var i = 0; i < imageData.data.length; i += 4) {
        // цвет обрабатываемого пикселя подлежит замене?
        if (imageData.data[i] == oldRed && imageData.data[i + 1] == oldGreen && imageData.data[i + 2] == oldBlue) {
            // меняем цвет
            imageData.data[i] = newRed;
            imageData.data[i + 1] = newGreen;
            imageData.data[i + 2] = newBlue;
        }
    }
    // заполняем холст измененными данными
    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    return c;
}

var oldImage = document.getElementById("old");
var newImage = document.getElementById("new");
var image = new Image();
var recoloredImage = null;
image.onload = function () {
    // Заменяем белый цвет (255, 255, 255) на черный (0, 0, 0)
    recoloredImage = recolorImage(image, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0);
    // Вставляем измененное изображение в документ
    newImage.src = recoloredImage.toDataURL('image/octet-stream');
};
image.src = oldImage.src;
```

Пример изображения, обработанного скриптом (слева исходное, справа новое)

[image: Пример]

Ответ написан на основе

- **[SO]** [Replace a specific color by another in an image/sprite in a HTML5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228048/replace-a-specific-color-by-another-in-an-image-sprite-in-a-html5-canvas)
- **[SO]** [How To Save Canvas As An Image With canvas.toDataURL()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673122/how-to-save-canvas-as-an-image-with-canvas-todataurl)

---

**Вариант для PHP**

- **[hashcode]** [Замена цвета](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/217951/php-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0)