# Нужно поменять цвет иконки

Tags: php

Как можно поменять цвет иконки средствами php?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А  как вы сами пробывали? И чем не устраивает хранить несколько разноцветных иконок.

Comment: Пробывал imagecolorset(); не вышло. Это крайний случай:)

Comment: Аналогичная проблема была решена [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/217951/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0)

Comment: Благодарю, посмотрю:)

Comment: Есть сервис https://img.icons8.com. Там лошадок можно запрашивать сразу в нужном цвете. Вот смотрите:
http://png.icons8.com/ios/2x/FF0000/horse-filled.png /
http://png.icons8.com/ios/2x/00FF00/horse-filled.png /
http://png.icons8.com/ios/2x/0000FF/horse-filled.png